# Problem installing mavensmate package in Atom

Tags: mavensmate, atom

I have already installed Mavensmate Desktop and is running. I installed atom and when I tried installing Mavensmate in Atom I get the following error.

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

I am installing on a mac OSX.

Comment: This question might be more on-topic on another exchange, like [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this might be because your machine has downloaded new version of xcode .You will need to open xcode app and accept the license .This should help you get rid of the error .

Or alternatively Follow these steps:

1.Open Terminal.

2.Enter this command: `sudo xcodebuild -license`.

3.Enter system password.

4.Agree to the license.